# Parallel for loop gives the wrong output

Tags: r

I'm trying to parallel a nested for loop using the foreach package. However, while the speed is much faster, it doesn't give the correct answer. The idea of this particular nested for loop is quite straightforward. The result (a number) of the most inside nested loop is added to the second layer loop, which is added to the third layer loop. Below is a reproducible data:

```
input <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*100, 1, .5), ncol=100))
input[input <0] =0
input2 <- split(input, f=input$X201)

d= 0
n= 0
j = 1
k = 1
f = 0
s= 0


cl <- parallel::makeCluster(20)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
tm1 <- system.time(

 results2 <- foreach(h = (1:length(input2)),.combine = 'c')%dopar%{
   return (   for (j in (1:nrow(input2[[h]]))){
     for (k in (1:nrow(input2[[h]]))){
       if (k != j) {

         for (i in (2:ncol(input2[[h]]))){
           if (input2[[h]][j,i] !=0){
             n= n+ (input2[[h]][j,i] * input2[[h]][k, i])
             d= d+ input2[[h]][j, i] * input2[[h]][j, i]
           }else {
             n= n
           }

         }
         f= f+ n/d* input2[[h]][k, 1]

       }

       n= 0
       d= 0
     }

     s= s+ f* input2[[h]][j,1]

     k = 1
     f = 0
   }
)
 } 


)
parallel::stopCluster(cl)
registerDoSEQ()
print("Cluster stopped.")
results2
```

The final output `results2` is Null. Additionally, after running the foreach loop, I found only i to be 8, h is 6 while k and j are 1 only, which seems wrong because I want k to be unequal to j at any time (as indicated in the code) and I expect h to be 10 (because there are 10 elements in the list). I also expect i to be 20 because within each element, there are 20 rows of dataframe. I wonder why I am wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2):

R foreach returns back results instead allows the outside variable to be changed. So don't expect d, n to be updated correctly. Treat the results as a way to do the map reduce and do the parallel for the most top for loop.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` does not update variable inside the loop. Consider the following example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel); registerDoParallel(2)
j <- 1
out <- foreach(i=1:4, .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    j <- i*10
    c(i=i, j=j)
}
```

`j` is not updated.

```
j
[1] 1
```

Hence, one needs to return all variables of interest. In the example above, the values of `i` and `j` are returned as matrix.

```
> out
         i  j
result.1 1 10
result.2 2 20
result.3 3 30
result.4 4 40
```